# The social group of Playframework?

Tags: java, facebook, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

Is there any social group (ex: facebook group, fans page..etc) discussing on playframework ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fairly active google group;

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/play-framework

and their gitHub location is;

https://github.com/playframework/play20

I believe both would qualify as social groups however I don't believe there is a specific facebook group.

Comment: I found the page on Facebook [Play!](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Play-Framework/50884087887), but I am not sure it is the most active group for play! :p

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/playone for Play 1.x